# Reorder an N x 4 pandas dataframe into an N x 2 so that triplicate dataset it arranged into one x column and one y column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a triplicate dataset that looks something like this:

```
conc rep1 rep2 rep3
0    0.1  0.2  0.1
1    3    3.2  2.8
```

And I want to reorganize it such that I have one x column (conc) and one y column:

```
conc y-data
0    0.1
0    0.2
0    0.1
1    3
1    3.2
1    2.8
```

I need it organized like this so I can feed it to a curve fit function which only takes in one column/list of x-data and one of y-data. How do I do this? I thought about cutting off each column with its x-values somehow, to have 3 dataframes with conc and rep#, and then concatenating into the N x 2 dataset structure I want. But I can't find how to do that. It might also be a bad way to go about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `melt`

```
df.melt('conc').drop('variable',1).sort_values('conc')
Out[40]: 
   conc  value
0     0    0.1
2     0    0.2
4     0    0.1
1     1    3.0
3     1    3.2
5     1    2.8
```

Comment: Yesssssss thank you! I knew there had to be an easy way to do it.